# Controlled impedance/coplanar wave design

Tags: controlled-impedance

We're using Diptrace at work which has no support for controlled impedance tracks.
I'm making a small 2 layer pcb for a TDR pulse generator, and would like to make one track about 50ohms impedance.

Using the [Saturn PCB Toolkit](http://www.saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit/), I get the following parameters for a 52ohms track on a FR4 board: 63 mils to groundplane (matches the pcb thickness specification), 40 mils conductor with 10 mils to the track surrounding it.

I've manually drawn a copper pour around the target track, connected it to the GND pour at the bottom layer using plenty of vias and defined the pour clearance at 10 mils. See screenshot:

[image]

Should this suffice? I realize this would probably not be sufficient for UHF/SHF/... work, but that's not what I'm aiming for at the moment.

Comment: It depends on your choice of FR4 . go with electrical tests.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Meaning "there can be small differences in the dielelctric constant"? I can understand that (and the benefit of actual testing), but is the general idea correct?

Comment: No . You can test and shop will,adjust  for 10% tolerance with testing and expect TBD otherwise

Comment: Make a test board with a few configurations of track width / spacing and measure with a microscope how close the manufactured board is to your gerber files. Measure trace impedancea. Expect 10-20% tolerance on the gaps unless you're willing to pay more for the mfg controlled impedance process.

Comment: Controlled Impedance = Electrical TDR Test’s